# ASP.NET mvc multiple routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-web-api-routing

I googled a lot of pages with the same issues but i couldn't solve my problem.
So I have this in the controller

```
public IEnumerable<questions> Get()
    {
        return (UOW.Questions.GetAll());
    }

    // GET api/questions/5
    public questions Get(int id)
    {
        return (UOW.Questions.GetById(id));
    }

    ////Basic Questions :: api/questions/basic
    [ActionName("basic")]
    public IEnumerable<questions> GetBasicQuestions()
    {
        return (UOW.Questions.GetBasicQuestions());
    }

    [ActionName("basic")]
    public questions GetBasicQuestionsById(int id)
    {
        return (UOW.Questions.GetBasicQuestions(id));
    }
```

and this in the WEbApiConfig :

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultController",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultControllerId",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: null,
            constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultActionId",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

I don't get whay when I enter localhost/api/questions and localhost/api/questions/1

gives me multiple route error...

Thank you..

Comment: You can use the route debugger available on nuget to see what routes are being hit: http://nuget.org/packages/routedebugger

Answer (score 0):

Change your routing to be as follows:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultController",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
    defaults: new { action = "GET" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultControllerId",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "GET" },
    constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultAction",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultActionId",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```